# Why does softmax give probability of 1 for outlier class?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, pytorch, softmax

I am trying to do open set classification by using a temperature scaled softmax and then interpreting the output probabilities as a confidence metric.

However, for complete outlier inputs, the temperature scaled softmax output is 0 everywhere else which indicates low confidence but then, invariably, 1 for the middle class which I presume is to compensate for all the other 0s such that the total probability adds up to 1.

How do I handle this situation? Or is there a reason why it's always the middle class that gets assigned a 1 i.e. is there a method to the madness which I can probably account for in my design?